# Why my migration M1 to M2 result in error 404 on all pages?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-2.1, migration

Any page including /admin which worked before data migration now displays:

> "There was no 404 CMS page configured or found"

Trying running

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php -f bin/magento cache:flush
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento indexer:reindex
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

after successfully migrating settings/data but still no luck.

I see products in MySQL if I connect to DB directly but no page is accessible and nothing is updating in var/log/*.logs

Went from 1.9.1.0 to 2.1.6

Thanks.

Comment: are u sure that ur category and product  pages are opening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run these commands in the root folder of your Magento installation:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
php -r "opcache_reset();"
mage deploy:mode:set developer; 
mage cache:flush &
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:static-content:deploy && 
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```